# Losing sessions in asp.net app after redirect

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, session, webmethod

I have two aspx pages, login.aspx and admin.aspx for example.

Both of them are calling to web methods, on all of the web methods the session is enabled of course.

After calling from login.aspx to web method to I'm saving in `session["user"]` the relevant object for the user.

The problem is after the redirection, on client-side after login I'm redirecting the user with `window.location = "admin.aspx"`, and when I'm making another call to another web method the `session["user"]` is null object.

Why is this happening? And how do I solve the issue?

Comment: This is one of those cases where creating an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful.

Comment: Upload your design code and code-behind. I'm sure that you have errors in your code